# Implicit cast an object to an array with one element. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Can I implicitly create an array from one single element in C#?

For instance, I have this method

```
public void MyMethod(string[] arrayString)
```

At some point in my code I have

```
string str = "myStr";
MyMethod(str)
```

Of course the second linhe is an error, because I am passing a string while MyMethod expects a string[].
Is there any clean way to call MyMethod without using

```
MyMethod(new string[] {str})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) array, this will be fine:

```
public void MyMethod(params string[] arrayString)

string str = "myStr";
MyMethod(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know would be to overload the method, so that you also have

```
MyMethod(string)
{
    return MyMethod(new string[] {str});
}
```

You might be able to do it with a `params` array, but I'm not entirely sure how that would work if you tried to pass in a string array, rather than multiple strings.

Comment: You can pass an array to a `params` argument, so "how it would work" == transparently.

Answer (score 1):

I would just add a second overload of `MyMethod`

```
public void MyMethod(string str)
{
    MyMethod(new[]{str});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here's another couple of options, though surely not recommended -- I'd use `params` as in the accepted answer.

```
MyMethod(Enumerable.Repeat(str, 1).ToArray());
```

I've also seen this on occasion, though it's hard to justify unless you're unaware of array initializers:

```
T[] MakeArray<T>(params T[] elements)
{
    return elements;
}
```

used thus:

```
string[] grades = MakeArray("A", "B", "C", "D", "F", "Incomplete");
```

or, in this case:

```
MyMethod(MakeArray(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about an extension method?

```
public static T[] WrapInArray<T>(this T t)
{
    return new T[]{ t };
}
```